# objective c create dynamic query to pass to sqlite3_prepare_v2

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, objective-c-2.0

I should create a query to pass to sqlite3_prepare_v2.

The query must be dynamic, and must allow me to retrieve all records that, in at least one field, containing at least one of the search filters.

For example:
-fields are f1, f2
-filters are SF1, SF2

I need to create dynamically:
  where f1 like '%SF1%' or f1 like '%sf2%' or f2 like '%SF1%' or f2 like '%sf2%'

Can you show the code that does what I described?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectStmt = nil;

NSString strParam1 = @"%SF1%";
NSString strParam2 = @"%SF2%";

const char *selectSql;

//prepare select statement
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &selectStmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
//Bind your parameter
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 1, [strParam1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
sqlite3_bind_text(selectStmt, 2, [strParam2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    while(sqlite3_step(selectStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
    {
      //Read your values from database
      NSString *f1Value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 0)];
      NSString *f2Value = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStmt, 1)];

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I solved by concatenating the nsmutablestrings and then I did:

char * myquery = [mynsmutablestring UTF8String]

The use of sqlite3_bind is the best approach?